# SQL server Convert varchar to time and calculate total time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I convert a `varchar(10)` with mixed values to time and calculate the total time from a recordset where the time values are not consistently formatted?

The values have been entered as text like this:

```
9:57
4:26
6:05
14:17
0:44
1:17
72:50
```

The total time should come to 01:48:56 (1 hour, 48 minutes and 56 seconds)

I have tried both: `CAST(Tracktime) AS TIME` and `CONVERT(TIME,Tracktime)` but neither work. There are hundreds of thousands of records I need to work through so it's not something easy to fix by manually replacing all the original data.

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't have a data type designed for working with time *spans*. The `time` data type is designed for holding a *time of day*. Those are different things. It doesn't make sense to add two (or more) times of day together, nor does it make sense to have a negative time of day nor one that exceeds 24 hours. That makes it a poor fit for use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @t table (dt varchar(10))
insert into @t 
values ('9:57'), ('4:26'), ('6:05'), ('14:17'), ('0:44'), ('1:17'), ('72:50')

select ([sum_min]+[sum_sec]/60)/60 [hours],--(amount of minutes)/60, i.e. how many hours
       ([sum_min]+[sum_sec]/60)%60 [minutes],--how many minutes
       [sum_sec]%60 [seconds]--how many seconds
from (
    --simple casting text to integers and summing them
    select sum(cast(SUBSTRING(dt,1,charindex(':',dt)-1) as int)) [sum_min],
           sum(cast(SUBSTRING(dt,charindex(':',dt)+1,2) as int)) [sum_sec]
    from @t
) [a]
```

Comment: Many thanks. This worked for me. All I had to do was change the source to my table with a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert your values to time or datetime since 72:50 is incompatible time. So you need to calculate total manually. Query calculates total seconds, then converts to needed format

```
declare @t table (dt varchar(10))
insert into @t 
values ('9:57'), ('4:26'), ('6:05')
    , ('14:17'), ('0:44'), ('1:17'), ('72:50')

select
    right(concat('0', seconds / 3600), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', seconds % 3600 / 60), 2)
     + ':' + right(concat('0', seconds % 60), 2)
from (
    select 
        seconds = sum(left(dt, ci-1) * 60 + substring(dt, ci + 1, len(dt)))
    from 
        @t
        cross apply (select ci = charindex(':', dt)) q
) t
```

`Concat` is available from SQL Server 2012. If your have lower version just convert computed value to varchar before concatenating with '0'

Comment: Many thanks but our version of SQL Server does not support CONCAT